# How to put a static text (postfix, prefix) in QLineEdit?

Tags: macos, qt, qlineedit

How can I put a static text in [QLineEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlineedit.html) in Qt C++ so that it can not be deleted and when I write to QLineEdit, it should not be spaced.

Comment: Could you provide an example of usage? I can't get what should happen with the static text when you type new text.

Comment: Are you talking about a Prefix/Postfix String thats always present?

Comment: for example: the qlineedit is used for putting weight so I want at the end of the line edit to be written: kg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no regular way to put a prefix or postfix in `QLabel`.

### Placeholder

As far as you can get with `QLineEdit` is to set a text which will be displayed when there is no text indide - see `QLineEdit::placeholderText`.

[image]

### InputMask

Another way to do it with `QLineEdit` is to set `inputMask` but it will change a cursor and will require a specific amount of letters.

[image]

### Postfix with QLabel

If you know maximum amount of symbols and want to make a postfix, you can get it with another `QLabel`:
1. Limit `length` of the text to have a certain free space at right.
2. Place `QLabel` to the right side of the `QLineEdit` and enter a postfix text into it.

NOTE: you won't be able to put `QLabel` on `QLineEdit` in QtDesigner if the `QLineEdit` is inside of a layout. In this case you can add `QWidget` instead of `QLineEdit` in the layout and put `QLineEdit` and `QLabel` within this widget which doesn't have a layout. Also you can create `QLabel` in the code:

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel(this);
label->setText("kg");
label->move(lineEdit->rect().right() - label->width() - 3, lineEdit->rect().center().y() - label->height() / 2);
```

[image]

### Custom Widget

Most flexible way to add a postfix and a prefix is to create a new class inherited from `QWidget` add two `QLabels` (prefix and postfix) info it, add `QLineEdit` between them and use css to make them look like a single `QLineEdit`.

[image]

On this image: Prefix and postfix are `QLabels`. _some_text_ is `QLineEdit` named `lineEdit` and all of them are inside a `QWidget` named `complexLineEdit` in a horizontal layout.

Here is a css I used for the image above:

```
QWidget#complexLineEdit
{
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; 
  background-color: white;
}

QWidget#complexLineEdit QLineEdit#lineEdit
{
   border: 0px;
}
```

You can play with it to make it even more similar to `QLineEdit`.

Comment: how can I enter a postfix to label?

Comment: I mean postfix text. Use regular `text` property. Added css and screenshots of all choices.

Comment: `postfixLabel->setText("some text");`

Comment: but what is this postfix label? where can I find this?

Comment: Create QLabel in QtDesigner or in the code and "Place QLabel to the right side of the QLineEdit".

Comment: Added a NOTE to 'Postfix with QLabel' section.

Answer (score 0):

I would just dynamically re-add the suffix after each text change.

My answer is in Python, but hopefully you get the idea behind it and it can help users from the future.

```
def __init__(self):

    ...
    # Connect the .textChanged signal of your QLineEdit to the method below.
    self.ui.weight_le.textChanged.connect(self.enforce_line_edit_suffix)
    ...


def enforce_line_edit_suffix(self):
    """This method parses the QLineEdit text and makes sure the desired suffix is there."""

    text = self.ui.weight_le.getText()

    if not text.endswith("kg"):
        self.ui.weight_le.blockSignals(True) # Prevent recursive calls to this method.
        self.ui.weight_le.setText(text + "kg")
        self.ui.weight_le.blockSignals(False)
```

Alternatively, if you need several `QLineEdit`s to behave like that, you could use:

```
def __init__(self):

    ...
    # Connect the .textChanged signal of your QLineEdit's to the method below
    # and force the "suffix" parameter.
    self.ui.weight_le.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.enforce_line_edit_suffix(suffix="kg"))
    self.ui.bias_le.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.enforce_line_edit_suffix(suffix="V"))
    self.ui.capacitance_le.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.enforce_line_edit_suffix(suffix="µF"))
    ...


def enforce_line_edit_suffix(self, suffix):
    """This method parses the QLineEdit text and makes sure the desired suffix is there."""

    line_edit = self.sender() # A reference to which QLineEdit triggered the method.
    text = line_edit.getText()

    if not text.endswith(suffix):
        line_edit.blockSignals(True) # Prevent recursive calls to this method.
        line_edit.setText(text + suffix)
        line_edit.blockSignals(False)
```

For extra safety, we could also imagine checking whether the text (once stripped of the suffix) contains only `+-.,0123456789`, otherwise your user could type `1.23 kgkg` and that would still work.